# Quadratic Residues Mod p

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Suppose that $p>3$ is a prime, and suppose also that $3|(p−1)$. Let $m= \frac{(p−1)}{3}$. Find and prove a simple condition or set of conditions for $p$ mod 12 that determine when $m$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.

---

I know the obvious truth that $3|(p-1)$ means that $(p-1)=3k$ where $k$ is some integer. Is this just dictated by the fact that $m=\frac{(p-1)}{3}$? Is this just saying that $k$ and $m$ are the same thing?

If so, how does any of this help me? Quadratic residues have always been tough for me.

Comment: $-3m\equiv1\pmod p$. This means that $m$ and $-3$ have the same character modulo $p$; they are both quadratic residues or both quadratic nonresidues. What do you know about whether $-3$ is a quadratic residue?

Comment: Essentially $m=-1/3$. So if you know whether $-1$ and $3$ are quadratic residues modulo $p$ you are in business. The law of quadratic reciprocity is your friend. The stuff about $-1$ is a well known (and well advertised) special case.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I'm not sure where you are getting the assumption that $-3m\equiv 1 (mod p)$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I also am not quite sure how you are assuming that $m=\frac {-1}{3}$ if $p$ must be greater than 3

Comment: I wasn't making an assumption, I was **calculating**:  $-3m = 1-p$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If you are manipulating $m=\frac {p-1}{3}$, then wouldn't $3m$ be positive?

Comment: And wouldn't $-3m$ be negative?

Comment: I apologize. I didn't catch that. In that case, I know that POSITIVE 3 is a quadratic residue when $p=\pm 1 mod 12$ and it is a quadratic non residue when $p=\pm 5 mod 12$, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how you were able to conclude that $-3m\equiv 1 mod p$

Comment: Well, $m=(3p-1)/3$, so $3m=p-1$ and $-3m=-(p-1)=1-p$. Then $1-p\equiv1\pmod p$ so $-3m\equiv1\pmod p$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57787/discussion-between-m-paul-and-lord-shark-the-unknown).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $p$ is a prime number such that $p \not= 2,3$ then using the idea that (Lord Shark pointed out) if $-3$ is quadratic residue $\mod p$ then also $m$ so we will work out when $-3$ is quadratic residue and the laws of Legendre symbol (found in this Wikipedia page [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol)).

which are :

1 ) $\left( \frac{-1}{p} \right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} $ which is equal $1$ if $p= 1 \mod 4$ and equals $-1$ if $p=3 \mod 4$.

2 ) $\left( \frac{q}{p} \right) \left( \frac{p}{q} \right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2} \frac{q-1}{2}}$

and substitute in the second law $q=3$, we get 
 $\left( \frac{3}{p} \right) \left( \frac{p}{3} \right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2} \frac{3-1}{2}}$ which means that :

$\left( \frac{3}{p} \right) = \left( \frac{p}{3} \right) (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$

Now we know that $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ which is the first law, and $\left( \frac{p}{3} \right)$ equals $1$ when $p=1 \mod 3$ and equals $-1$ when $p=2 \mod 3$.

Combining all the above we can say that $m$ is quadratic residue $\mod p$ when :
 $p=1,7 \mod 12$ and quadratic non-residue $\mod p$ when $p =5,11 \mod 12$.

(**Hint**) in your case because $5,11-1 \mod 3 \not=0 $ then if we restrict $m$ to be integer  for all primes which fulfill the condition that $m$ is integer,$m$ will be quadratic residue $\mod p$